# beaglebone black debian 10 where does the IP addresses on USB0 and USB1 come from and how to eliminate them?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, beaglebone

```
#>ip a
```

on my debian 10 install on the beaglebone black shows two unwanted interfaces, USB0 and USB1 having IP addresses assigned to it.
I tried to figure out where do they come from and how to get rid of them, but with no luck.
I apt purged cannman so I've only the systemd controlled networking going.

```
dpkg -l |grep network
ii  dirmngr management service
ii  ifupdown
ii  iproute2
ii  iputils-ping 
ii  net-tools
ii  netbase
```

I like to have a really basic, static, server like network config like in the old days.

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific feature of the beagleboard.org images. Those are meant to help users access the device via USB networking. There are two because there are many standards and none that work everywhere.

This is controlled by boot scripts that are not part of a package and are located in `/opt/scripts/`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42666437/2648865

If you run an up to date image, then this should be very close to the files there: https://github.com/RobertCNelson/boot-scripts/tree/master/boot

**Update:** If you are looking for a clean base to build up from, consider a "Console" image. It only brings the bare minimum and does not configure any fancy things. Notably it does not configure/enable USB-networking. You're expected to access it via the debug-UART (not its USB port) or via Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. (I tried to upvote, but not enough credits yet.)
Thanks, a lot. That gives me an idea where to look. 
I've still to figure out where and how that scripts get called.

Comment: Image builder (one of many scripts):https://github.com/RobertCNelson/omap-image-builder/blob/master/configs/bb.org-debian-buster-lxqt-v5.4.conf#L168
Also if you want a bare system and build up from that, you should consider trying a "console" image instead.

Comment: Regarding the "Console" image, yes, I did use the console image from beagle board support page. There is an IoT image as well, I might give that a try.

Comment: The IoT image used to be a "full image", but minus the desktop UI packages (HDMI output).